# Java Performance Measurement on Objects from external JARs

Tags: java, performance, interceptor

I want to measure the performance (mainly execution time) on specific methods of external JARs. For that I already read some other threads but all proposals are not working for me.

Basically the following proposals were made:

1. **Java Proxies** are not working for me because I have no control over
   the object creation and the method invocation. The objects are
   created outside of our application and also getting invoked from
   there. We are just using the created object and setting some
   configuration parameters allowing the object to be called at some
   time by the framework.
2. **AOP (e.g. AspectJ) at build time**: the classes which we're using are already deployed on the server and won't be build by us.
3. **AOP (e.g. AspectJ) at run time**: as far as I see this needs server configuration which is not allowed by the customer.
4. **Decompilation of the classes and manual enhancement**: also not allowed by the customer and most probably illegal.

I'm basically searching for a solution that allows me to attach a listener to specific method calls on specific objects. With that we would be able to measure the performance and we could even log some contextual information (e.g. current logged in user).

In a perfect world this might look like this, where to monitored object only will be monitored as long as it exists:

```
EpicMonitoring.monitor(objectToBeMonitored, "methodToBeMonitored", new AbstractMonitorListener(){
    public void onPreMethodInvocation(Object[] args)[
        // Start time measurement
    };

    public void onPostMethodInvocation()[
        // Stop time measurement
    };
});
```

As I ran out of ideas I hope some of you guys could help me finding some ideas on this :)

Comment: Are you invoking the specific methods of the objects in these external JARS? Or are you calling an external API which calls the methods that you're trying to monitor?

Comment: @RickRidley they are getting invoked by the framework at some point of time which I can't control. I basically only initialize those objects with same configuration parameters. They are getting created by the framework and also are getting further invoked by the framework.

Comment: So what is your overall goal? Are you trying to see how performance is affected based upon your configuration of the objects used by the framework?

Comment: @RickRidley the framework is basically doing lots of database operations. The database is our main point where we are working on performance optimizations. E.g. the framework is executing duplicate checks on the database which are taking up to 1 minute for the end user. The database has around 700k records with about 1000 fields in the relevant main table. To measure and to proof that our changes we did in the database are positively affecting our applications I want to measure those points where the database is involved.